# Spring Security without WebSecurityConfiguererAdapter, register two AuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

Since the deprication of WebSecurityConfiguererAdapter, I am not sure on how to implement my two custom AuthenticationProvider classes. Everything works in case I only use one of the AuthenticationProviders, but having two prevents both of them to function. I tried giving them `@Order` annotations but that doesn't work either. How would I register my custom AuthenticationProviders to make them work along each other and being called when the class defined in its support method matches. By the way, I'am a SpringBoot noob ;)

```
@Component
class AuthenticationService(
    private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager,
) {
    fun login(loginDto: LoginDto): Boolean {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
            Token2(
                loginDto.username, loginDto.password
            )
        )
        return true
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
class ProdSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager(authenticationConfiguration: AuthenticationConfiguration): AuthenticationManager {
        return authenticationConfiguration.authenticationManager
    }

    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable()
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        return http.build()
    }
}
```

```
@Component
class CredentialsAuthProvider : AuthenticationProvider {

    override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication): Authentication {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            "myUser@mailbox.org", "password"
        )
    }

    override fun supports(authentication: Class<*>?): Boolean {
        return authentication == Token1::class.java
    }
}
```

```
@Component
class CredentialsAuthProvider2 : AuthenticationProvider {

    override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication): Authentication {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            "myUser@mailbox.org", "password"
        )
    }

    override fun supports(authentication: Class<*>?): Boolean {
        return authentication == Token2::class.java
    }
}
```

Comment: you shouldnt even implement custom AuthenticationProviders.

Comment: And why is that? Whats the point in making it possible to implement one if you can't use it?

Comment: Its not narrow minded to explain to you that you should not write custom security. Writing custom security is in general bad practice and it is narrow minded to not understand that.

Comment: Well I'm working with one of the most flexible frameworks out there, which does not provide the authentication I need out of the box, but offers the possibility to tweak it the way I need it to be. I think this is what a developer does, creating solutions, not saying one can't or one shouldn't.

Comment: Are you willing to take the economic responsabillity the next time a custom security solution has a vulnerability?

Comment: I think you over dramatize what I'm doing here, there is even a baeldung tutorial for what I'm doing here, just with the difference, that I implement two custom AuthenticationProvider instead of just one. It is still spring security that secures my app. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider

Comment: Just because there is a tutorial doesn’t mean its good practice

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `@Component` annotation from my custom `AuthenticationProviders`, I created `@Beans` in my SecurityConfiguration class for each custom `AuthenticationProvider` where I directly call their constructor instead of using springs DI. Then used them within my `AthenticationManager` Bean where I return a `ProviderManager`.

Code snippets for explanation:

```
@Configuration
class ProdSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun credentialsAuthProvider(): AuthenticationProvider {
        return CredentialsAuthProvider()
    }

    @Bean
    fun credentialsAuthProvider2(): AuthenticationProvider {
        return CredentialsAuthProvider2()
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager(): AuthenticationManager {
        return ProviderManager(listOf(credentialsAuthProvider(), credentialsAuthProvider2()))
    }

    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable()
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        return http.build()
    }
}
```